# GarbageCollection does not release of memory in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, garbage-collection

I am worried about my application because the longer I use it, the more memory it consumes. I am using Silverlight-enabled WCF service to retrieve datas from the database. 
Let me explain the application. There is DataGrid and a `frame` in `MainPage`. User enters some datas and after clicking `Search` button, service gets datas from database and fills the DataGrid. And after this, user can select row and application changes URI of the frame from the ViewModel like that:

```
// Sending selectedId as Query string
FrameURI = new Uri(
                   string.Format("/Views/PersonDetails.xaml?SelectedID={0}",
                   SelectedID,
                   UriKind.Relative);
```

I am getting datas of the person with the given ID in `OnNavigatedTo` event and calling a method which return object with the type of Person:

```
    _id = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedID"];

    if (_id != "")
    {
        Uri address = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../UserServiceName.svc"); 
        UserServiceNameClient client = new UserServiceNameClient("CustomBinding_UserServiceName", address.AbsolutePath);

        client.GetPersonByIDCompleted += (sender, event) =>
            {
                   if (e.Result.Name != null)
                   {
                         LayoutRoot.DataContext = (Person)e.Result;
                   }
            };
        client.GetPersonByIDAsync(_id);
    }
```

But the problem is here. It seems that GC is not kicking in after selecting new id from the DataGrid. After changing selected row in DataGrid, memory of the application keeps growing up. And the storyboards/animations become laggy...

I have read some posts in web, some of them tell that, it is about `event handlers`. I have tried somethings, but didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: use windbg to debug and see which objects and types are rooted and why. just Google for WinDbg WPF memory leaks

Comment: I don't think the GC will kick in just because you are changing the Data.  The GC kicks in when the GC think's it should kick in.  I really don't think the issue with your app getting laggy is because of the GC.